# Daemon. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Tags: python, daemon, attributeerror, nonetype

Please help me with the error.  I have a simple code that I run on Linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import daemon
import sys
from traceback import format_exc


def run_main_function():
    print("Hello")

try:
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        run_main_function()
except:
    print(sys.stdin)
    print(format_exc())
```

The script is unstable.  The script sometimes fails and sometimes executes successfully.  I ask for help in solving the problem.

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/logstash_stats.py", line 18, in <module>
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 249, in __init__
    detach_process = is_detach_process_context_required()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 817, in is_detach_process_context_required
    if is_process_started_by_init() or is_process_started_by_superserver():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 795, in is_process_started_by_superserver
    if is_socket_file(sys.__stdin__):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daemon/daemon.py", line 759, in is_socket_file
    file_fd = file.fileno()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I tried to set stdin manually, but it didn't work.
Google search didn't help me.

New details:
The problem is not related to the daemon library.  My script periodically returns NoneType when I execute simple code.

```
import sys

print(sys.stdin)
```

return:

```
None
```

My script calls zabbix.  The rights to the script were issued correctly.  I do not know what the problem is.

```
chown zabbix:zabbix /path/script
chmod 0777 /path/scrypt
```

Tell me what can be done?

Comment: The error message has `with daemon.DaemonContext(pidfile=PidFile(PIDNAME, PIDDIR), files_preserve=[my_file.fileno()]):` which does not match the code.  Please post the real code.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Corrected.

Comment: Решение нашлось в русском сообществе stackoverflow:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566994/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd-none-sys-stdin-none